# How create a instance of class with dependent in constructor from startup.cs(ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create email client in my asp.net core web application.I have created a class with some DB service as dependent and I have a method inside this class which will connect to the mail box and starts listening to it on a separate thread.But I'm unable to create an instance of the class from the startup.cs file because I unable pass IDBxxxxService to the constructor.

```
  var serviceProvider = Services.BuildServiceProvider();
        serviceProvider.CreateInstance<MailEvents>().MailSubscribe(new IMAPConnection
        {
            Host = "imap.gmail.com",
            EnableOAuth = false,
            Port = 993,
            EnableSSL = true,
            UserName = "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            Password = "9xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        });
```

and here is extension method i have written to create the instance using reflection.

```
public static TResult CreateInstance<TResult>(this IServiceProvider provider) where TResult: class
    {
        ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(TResult).GetConstructors()[0];

        if (constructor != null)
        {
            object[] args = constructor
                .GetParameters()
                .Select(o => o.ParameterType)
                .Select(o => provider.GetService(o))
                .ToArray();

            return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TResult), args) as TResult;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Register all the other dependencies with the service collection. That way when asking for your service the container will have all it needs to hydrate the object graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume your class looks something like

```
public class MailEvents {
    public MailEvents(IDbxxxService db) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Register all the other dependencies with the service collection in the composition root.

```
Services.AddSingleton<IDbxxxService, DbxxxService>(); //Choose appropriate lifetime
Services.AddSingleton<MailEvents>();
```

That way when asking for your service the service provider will have all it needs to hydrate the object graph.

```
var serviceProvider = Services.BuildServiceProvider();
serviceProvider.GetService<MailEvents>().MailSubscribe(new IMAPConnection
{
    Host = "imap.gmail.com",
    EnableOAuth = false,
    Port = 993,
    EnableSSL = true,
    UserName = "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    Password = "9xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
});
```

You can also use one of the overloaded methods as well

```
//if you need to manually create dependency you have that option as well
//in case you needed to add other customizations.
Services.AddSingleton<IDbxxxService>(provider => new  DbxxxService()); //Choose appropriate lifetime
```

Comment: But in my case, DbxxxService has few more dependents. e.g DbxxxService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IMapper mapper)

Comment: They would also need to be registered as well or use the overload and create them your self when registering your service. Service provider needs to be aware of everything it can create.